# xslt grouping flat content to multiple listing

Tags: xml, list, xslt

I have searched for the following problem, but I can't find the right solution.

I have flat listing:

```
<list>
<p class="1">1. Voice of the Customer/Business/Process /Employee</p>
<p class="1">2. Value add trefwoord 4:</p>
<p class="2">a. Waste</p>
<p class="2">b. Process flow:</p>
<p class="3">- Process flow</p>
<p class="1">3. SIPOC</p>
<p class="1">4. Takt time</p>
</list>
```

I want to transform this xml in a multiple list with hierarchy like this:

```
<list>
<listitem><p class="1">1. Voice of the Customer/Business/Process /Employee</p></listitem>
<listitem><p class="1">2. Value add trefwoord 4:</p>
<list>
<listitem><p class="2">a. Waste</p></listitem>
<listitem><p class="2">b. Process flow:</p>
<list> 
<listitem><p class="3">- Process flow</p></listitem>
</list> 
</listitem>
</list>
</listitem> 
<listitem><p class="1">3. SIPOC</p></listitem>
<listitem><p class="1">4. Takt time</p></listitem>
</list>
```

I tried with several grouping code but I don't get it right. Could someone help me please. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359677/need-help-nesting-siblings/35360206#35360206 for instance for a similar question and an XSLT 1.0 solution.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34927607/how-can-i-get-a-sequence-of-elements-with-a-defined-level-into-an-element-struct/34928780#34928780 for an XSLT 2.0 solution to a similar question.