# Need paras as sections main and sub levels heading with h levels

Tags: xslt, dita, dita-ot

Paras with different outputclasses as heading sections as main and sub levels

My input xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic
  PUBLIC "urn:pubid:doctypes:dita:topic" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="topic_1" xml:lang="en-US" outputclass="Sec-Chapter">
  <title>Sec-Chapter</title>
  <body>
    <p outputclass="Title">Heading Mappings</p>
    <p outputclass="A-Head">A-Head</p>
    <p>Some paragraph text</p>
    <p outputclass="B-Head">B-Head</p>
    <p>Some more paragraph text</p>
    <p outputclass="C-Head">C-Head</p>
    <p>Yet more paragraph text</p>
    <p outputclass="D-Head">D-Head</p>
    <p>Some creative paragraph text</p>
    <p outputclass="E-Head">E-Head</p>
    <p>Now, boing paragraph text</p>
    <p outputclass="F-Head">F-Head</p>
    <p>Finally, end</p>
  </body>
</topic>
```

XSL template I have used for the heading level creation:

```
    <xsl:template match="//body">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="//p[@outputclass = 'A-head']">
        <h2><xsl:value-of select="//p[@outputclass = 'A-head']"/></h2>
        <section>
<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="//p[@outputclass = 'B-head']">
            <h3><xsl:value-of select="//p[@outputclass = 'B-head']"/></h3>
            <section>
<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
              <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="//p[@outputclass = 'C-head']">
                <h4><xsl:value-of select="//p[@outputclass = 'C-head']"/></h4>
                <section>
<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                  <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="//p[@outputclass = 'D-head']">
                    <h5><xsl:value-of select="//p[@outputclass = 'D-head']"/></h5>
                    <section>
<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                      <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="//p[@outputclass = 'E-head']">
                        <h6><xsl:value-of select="//p[@outputclass = 'E-head']"/></h6>
                        <section>
<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                          <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="//p[@outputclass = 'F-head']">
                            <h6><xsl:value-of select="//p[@outputclass = 'F-head']"/></h6>
                            <section>
                              <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                            </section>
                          </xsl:for-each-group>
                        </section>
                      </xsl:for-each-group>
                    </section>
                  </xsl:for-each-group>
                </section>
              </xsl:for-each-group>
            </section>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </section>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

I am getting output using above template as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xml:lang="en-us" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Heading</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>A-Head</h2>
        <section></section>
        <h2>A-Head</h2>
        <section>
           <h3>B-Head</h3>
           <section></section>
           <h3>B-Head</h3>
           <section>
              <h4>C-Head</h4>
              <section></section>
              <h4>C-Head</h4>
              <section>
                 <h5>D-Head</h5>
                 <section></section>
                 <h5>D-Head</h5>
                 <section>
                    <h6>E-Head</h6>
                    <section></section>
                    <h6>E-Head</h6>
                    <section>
                       <h6>F-Head</h6>
                       <section>
                          <p class="p">Now, boing paragraph text</p>

                       </section>
                       <h6>F-Head</h6>
                       <section>
                          <h6>F-Head</h6>

                       </section>
                    </section>
                 </section>
              </section>
           </section>
        </section>
     </body>
</html>
```

but I need output as `A-head` as `h2` main level section, `B-Head` as `h3` sub level section for `h2`, `C-Head` as `h4` sub level section for `h3`, `D-Head` as `h5` sub level section for `h4`, `E-Head` as `h6` sub level section for `h5`, `F-Head` as `h6` same level section as `h6` as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xml:lang="en-us" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Heading</title>
    </head>
    <body class="Section" id="topic_1">
        <section>
            <p class="TitleTtl">Heading2</p>
            <h2>A-Head</h2>
            <section>
                <p class="p">Some paragraph text</p>
                <h3>B-Head</h3>
                <section>
                    <p class="p">Some more paragraph text</p>
                    <h4>C-Head</h4>
                    <section>
                        <p class="p">Yet more paragraph text</p>
                        <h5>D-Head</h5>
                        <section>
                            <p class="p">Some creative paragraph text</p>
                            <h6>E-Head</h6>
                            <section>
                                <p class="p">Now, boing paragraph text</p>
                            </section>
                            <h6>F-Head</h6>
                            <section>
                                <p class="p">Finally, end</p>
                            </section>
                        </section>
                    </section>
                </section>
            </section>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The only XSLT template you have shown has a match pattern `*[contains(@class, ' topic/p ')]` so it will be applied to any element having a `class` attribute containing ` topic/p ` in its value. I don't see any such element with a `class` attribute in your XML. Does the DTD predefine that attribute?

Comment: @MartinHonnen The original XML is DITA content so the class attribute values come as default values defined in the associated DOCTYPE DTD. In my opinion this is a case in which you initially have a flat sequence of nodes and you need to convert it to a hierarchy of nodes, so probably for-each group is the way to go. I found a previous topic describing a similar situation, its last two possible solutions are either by using for-each group or by using xslt keys: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755857/xslt-create-a-hierarchical-structure-from-a-flat-structure-by-using-certain-leve

Comment: Hi @Martin Honnen, Its a Dita OT epub plugin xslt template, so its applying to the any topic file which contains topic inside p element. Please suggest.

Comment: Radu has linked to a similar question with two solutions, try to adapt them to your input/wanted output.

Comment: @Martin Hionnen I have tried with that answer but i can't recall this for this question can you suggest

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen, I have edited my xslt code please suggest me in that format how i can get the resultant output. Thanks in Advance